# checking next and previous indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I'm trying to go through each index and check if it's greater than the next index or not, but I could not come up with any idea about how to do it. I tried using `range` and `enumerate` functions, but did not work so help would be much appreciated. This is my current code:

```py
user_input = input("Anything: ")
user_input = user_input.split(",")
arrayList = [int(i) for i in user_input]
test = []

for the_index, the_item in enumerate(arrayList):
```

Here is what I tried earlier than this

```py
user_input = input("Anything: ")
user_input = user_input.split(",")
arrayList = [int(i) for i in user_input]
first_numbers = []
second_numbers = []
finalList = []

for i in arrayList:
    the_index = arrayList.index(i)
    if the_index % 2 != 0:
        first_numbers.append(i)
    if the_index % 2 == 0:
        second_numbers.append(i)

first_numbers.append(second_numbers)
```

Comment: can you add your input and expected output

Comment: Could you please clarify: you want to step through a `list` of numbers and compare each element to the previous and the next? What should happen based on the result of the comparison?

Comment: Exactly that and the output should be the numbers that were greater than the numbers next to them,

Comment: the output should be like:
if user input is a list of: 1,3,2,4,11,7,9, 5

output: 
 3 > 2,
 11 > 7,
 9 > 5,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i got this clear but if you want to know if user's input was **bigger** **/** **smaller** than the previous choice, you can do this:

This may not be the shortest way to do it, but this is a dynamic snippet where you can decide ask as much as inputs you want the user to answer:

```py
user_choice = input('Choose some numbers: ')
user_choice_listed = user_choice.split(',')

marked_choice = None # Uninitialized integer that would be assigned in the future
for t in user_choice_listed:

    converted_t = int(t)

    if marked_choice != None and marked_choice < converted_t:
        print('{0} is Bigger than your previous choice, it was {1}'.format(t,marked_choice))
    elif marked_choice != None and marked_choice > converted_t:
        print('{0} is Smaller than your previous choice, it was {1}'.format(t,marked_choice))
    elif marked_choice == None:
        print('This is your first Choice, nothing to compare with!')

    marked_choice = converted_t # this is marking the previous answer of the user
```

**NOTE**: You can add a line to handle where the previous is **equal** to the current choice.

**OUTPUT:**

```py
Choose some numbers: 1,3,5 # My Input

This is your first Choice, nothing to compare with!
3 is Bigger than your previous choice, it was 1
5 is Bigger than your previous choice, it was 3
```

Comment: Understood your code, really big thanks for it, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is get list of integers from user and go through each number and check if it's greater than the next one. So this is an user input: [1,6,5,8,7,11,9] and I must get(6 is bigger than 5, 8 is bigger than 7, 11 is bigger than 9) as an output

Comment: Hey dante, see my edit please.

This time, the input accepts a list of numbers divided by comma (,) , and then there is a convertion to list of integers. This will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and for the help, I really appreciate it. Huge thanks to you ;

Comment: By the way could you explain what does the marked_choice does here?

Comment: Yes, i store every integer in marked choice **after** all the execution of the code, and in the second run, marked_choice is not stored **yet** with the next integer, so it remembers the previous one.

And obviously, it has to be initialized **outside** of the loop as None.
Because you cannot compare your first integer with the previous, as there is no previous, and i do handle it by outputting that this is the first integer.

Answer (score 0):

Loop it through the indexes?

```
for i in range(len(arrayList)):
     if arrayList[i] > arrayList[i + 1]:
         //enter code here
```

Comment: in that case I'm getting out of index range error :/

Comment: `for i in range(len(arrayList)-1):` This will stop the index out of range error if you are comparing one item with the next item.